# How can i recive a row response as json string from RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to get the actual json i recieve as response from rest service.
My problem is that i have multiple message converters configured for my RestTemplate like this.

```
  @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.build();
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
        return restTemplate;
    }

    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new LinkedList<>();

        StringHttpMessageConverter textConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(textConverter);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(jsonConverter);

        HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);

        return converters;
    }
```

Here is the how i try to retrive the string from the response.

```
 ResponseEntity<String> message = null;
        try {
            message = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                    url,
                    new HttpEntity<>(payload, getHeaders()),
                    String.class);
            return message.getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            log.error(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e);
        }
```

My guess is that because i have a Mapping2Jackson2HttpMessageConverter configured, each time i recieve message with content type application/json, it tries to convert it using json converter even if response type class is specified as String.

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: remove restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
 and test it again